# How to add a document menu in MFC application?

Tags: c++, mfc

when you click right click on any tab in visual studio a menu will appear containing some options like(Save, Close all but this, Copy full path, Open containing folder, ....).
How to add a menu like that in MFC(doc/view) tabbed application?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"MFC tabbed application"* could refer to many things. Please explain in more detail.

Comment: Tabs do not relate to the menus. As for the menus, your application almost always contains a main menu (usually IDR_MAINFRAME), and if you are using the doc/view feature, another one for every document type (doc template actually). This second one is related to the document type and is displayed when a document is active. Choose which menu you want to put your additional menu items to. Commands may be handled (depending on your data and design) by the document, view, or mainframe class.

Comment: yes, I'm using the doc/view feature. i mean that sometimes i have many opened doc templates and i can switch between them using the tabs in the top of the main frame.
and sometimes i want to close all the opened docs except one.
same as the option supported in visual studio when you have a multiple opened CPP files for example and you click on the upper tab and choose "Close all but this" @ConstantineGeorgiou

Comment: I'm using the doc/view feature. i mean that sometimes i have many opened doc templates and i can switch between them using the tabs in the top of the main frame. and sometimes i want to close all the opened docs except one. same as the option supported in visual studio when you have a multiple opened CPP files for example and you click on the upper tab and choose "Close all but this" @BarmakShemirani

Comment: Still, what does this have to do with the menu (your question was about the menu)? So, as said above add the menu item to the doc-template-specific menu, and a handler (ON_COMMAND). In the handler (put it in the document class), get the doc-template and populate the list of all its documents (`GetFirstDocPosition()`/`GetNextDoc()`). Close all open documents that are NOT equal to the current one (`this`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've handled the message `WM_RBUTTONUP` on the function `PreTranslateMessage` as following:

```
BOOL CMainFrame::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
  if( WM_RBUTTONUP == pMsg->message)
  {
    //check that the right click is on MDI tab area.
    CWnd* pWnd = FromHandle(pMsg->hwnd);
    CMFCTabCtrl* tabGroup = dynamic_cast<CMFCTabCtrl*>(pWnd);
    if (tabGroup)
    {
      CPoint clickLocation = pMsg->pt;
      tabGroup->ScreenToClient(&clickLocation);
      int tabIndex = tabGroup->GetTabFromPoint(clickLocation);
      if (tabIndex != -1)
      {
        CWnd* pTab = tabGroup->GetTabWnd(tabIndex);
        if (pTab)
        {
          CPoint point = pMsg->pt;
          ClientToScreen (&point);
          ShowPopupTabOptions(point);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return CMDIFrameWndEx::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have more than one menu. `IDR_MAINFRAME` is usually used when no documents are opened, that's not the one you want.

Resource editor should show another main menu (not a popup menu) whose ID is something like `IDR_MyAppTYPE`. This menu ID should already be in your `CWinAppEx` class:

```
BOOL CMyApp::InitInstance()
{
    ...
    pDocTemplate = new CMultiDocTemplate(IDR_MyAppTYPE, ...);
    ...
}
```

This is your document menu.

Edit this menu using the resource editor. Add the command `"Close all but this"` and the id for menu command would be something like `ID_WINDOW_CLOSEALL_BUT_THIS`

You have to handle this command in `CView` derived class. Example:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyView, CView)
    ON_COMMAND(ID_WINDOW_CLOSEALL_BUT_THIS, OnCloseAllButThis)
    ...
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CMyView::OnCloseAllButThis()
{
    POSITION p1 = AfxGetApp()->GetFirstDocTemplatePosition();
    while(p1)
    {
        CDocTemplate *doctempl = AfxGetApp()->GetNextDocTemplate(p1);
        POSITION p2 = doctempl->GetFirstDocPosition();
        while(p2)
        {
            CDocument* doc = doctempl->GetNextDoc(p2);
            POSITION p3 = doc->GetFirstViewPosition();
            while(p3)
            {
                CView* view = doc->GetNextView(p3);
                if(view && view->GetParentFrame() && view != this)
                    view->GetParentFrame()->SendMessage(WM_CLOSE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```